# v5.6.1 publish instance redirecting for certain files

Tags: aem

I started up a clean AEM 5.6.1 publish instance and am trying to change the default admin password. I went to http://localhost:4503/libs/granite/security/content/useradmin.html, but the page does not load correctly. I'm able to tell that some files load correctly (jquery.js, utils.js), but other files (userpicker.css, userpicker.js) respond with a JavaScript redirect:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">var u="/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/account/login.html?resource=%2Flibs%2Fgranite%2Fui%2Fcomponents%2Ffoundation%2Fform%2Fuserpicker%2Fclientlibs%2Fuserpicker.css&$$login$$=%24%24login%24%24"; if ( window.location.hash) {u = u + window.location.hash;} document.location = u;</script>
   </head>
   <body>
  <!-- QUICKSTART_HOMEPAGE - (string used for readyness detection, do not remove) -->
   </body>
</html>
```

What's interesting is that although I can't access userpicker.css, I am able to navigate to userpicker/userpicker.css without any problems.

Can someone explain what's happening here, and what I need to do to correct this behavior?

Comment: which user you had logged in and trying to reset the admin password.? check the browser debugging tool for the errors and blocked content.

Comment: I'm logged in as admin. All the browser requests result in 200 OK, but as stated, some responses are not the real files, but instead are these HTML files with JavaScript redirects.

Comment: Is your publisher configured for UGC? The login redirect looks like something configured for community users... just a hunch

Comment: I don't think so--I basically used the quickstart jar to create a new publish instance from scratch and immediately tried to change the admin password.